# Query HAVING MAX() doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, having-clause

I have four tables in a database. the tables are like the following:

```
Cashier(cashier_id*, cashier_name)
Category(category_id*, category_name)
Product(product_id*, product_name, price, category_id**)
Purchase(product_id**, cashier_id**, amount)

* primary key
** foreign key
```

I want to select category name with the highest number of purchase. Here's what I've done so far, but I couldn't get the result that i want

```
SELECT x.category,x.amount
    FROM (SELECT category_name as category, SUM(amount) as amount FROM 
          Category c, Product pr, Purchase pu WHERE pr.product_id = 
          pu.product_id and c.category_id = pr.category_id GROUP BY 
          category_name) x
    GROUP BY x.category
    HAVING MAX(x.amount);
```

Comment: If you use `,` in `from` clause, it will do a cross join.

Comment: As to `HAVING MAX(x.amount)`: Let's say the maximum amount is 5. So you get `HAVING 5`. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: Let's say there's some products with category A, and category A has the highest number of purchase. I want to get that category name and the number of its purchase

Comment: @MulqanJunaidi You have already got an answer. Please respond to it. Also, can you share your tables using [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?

Comment: @vivek_23 It works fine with Gordon Linoff's query. but I wonder if I can directly targeting to the highest number of purchase using MAX() instead of using LIMIT.

Comment: @Mulqan Junaidi I can try that for you if share tables and rows using sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT c.category_name as category, SUM(amount) as amount
FROM Category c JOIN
     Product pr
     ON c.category_id = pr.category_id JOIN
     Purchase pu 
     ON pr.product_id = pu.product_id
GROUP BY category_name
ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works as expected but I wonder if I can directly targeting to the highest number of purchase using MAX() instead of using LIMIT. btw, your query works perfectly I just want to know if I can use MAX() too. Thank you

Comment: @MulqanJunaidi . . . Not the way you were trying to use it.